# Keep Android Process (App) Running at All Times

Tags: android, process, android-source, keep-alive, android-dialer

Proglem:
Create custom Android App which will never be killed by the platform.

Given a Dialer app (or a phone-app), for making calls on Android Phone, is there a way to similarly create custom app and make it a system app, so that Android always keep it running?

In other words, the problem we have is to deploy an app which will never be killed by AOSP due to lack of resources or anything similar, which is what I think android does for Dialer and some other system apps/services.

Possible helpful hint: The device will always have power supply, as it is not a phone/tablet but rather a custom device running custom AOSP.

Comment: Have you tried adding android:persistent="true" in AndroidManifest.xml ( you'll have to be signed with platform certs for it to take effect )

Comment: I've heard that's the way to go, but the AOSP we will be using might not allow it, since it is from a vendor. I'll try to check. Btw is there a tutorial on how this is done?
Thanks tiny rick